# AutoCorrelation as a measurement of the second order moment

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, moments

I am reading the following document:

http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/applied/news.dir/issue2/hos_intro.html

In this page they mentioned that "In the time domain, the second order measure is the autocorrelation function".

I know the second moment is $\mathbb{E}(X\cdot X)$. If in the autocorrelation we set the lag to $0$ it makes sense; but how about the case when the lag in not $0$? Why is this still a second moment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Autocovariance** is second-order central cross-moment,
$$
\text{Cov}(X_t,X_{t-h})=\mathbb{E}(X_t-\mu_X)(X_{t-h}-\mu_X),
$$
where $\mu_X$ is the unconditional mean of $X$.

- It is "second-order" because it involves a product of two elements, $X_t$ and $X_{t-h}$.
- It is "central" as it considers deviations from the mean by subtracting $\mu_X$.
- It is "cross-moment" because the elements $X_t$ and $X_{t-h}$ are not the same.

**Autocorrelation** is scaled autocovariance, 
$$
\text{Corr}(X_t,X_{t-h})=\frac{ \text{Cov}(X_t,X_{t-h}) }{ \text{Cov}(X_t,X_t) }.
$$
It does not measure the second-order central cross-moment in *absolute* magnitude but only *relative* to the second-oder central moment $\text{Cov}(X_t,X_t)$ which is the variance of $X_t$:
$$
\text{Cov}(X_t,X_t)=\mathbb{E}(X_t-\mu_X)(X_t-\mu_X)=\mathbb{E}(X_t-\mu_X)^2=\text{Var}(X_t).
$$

Comment: many thanks for you complete answer! can I ask one more question if possible please? 
I read that :Second-order measures (such as the power spectrum and autocorrelation functions) contain no phase information. 
I don't really get that ! why higher orders statistic have phase information but the second order doesn't ?

Comment: @MEMS, you are welcome! I think you may post this as a separate question. It is advisable to keep distinct questions separate.